# How to embed vega in jupyterlab or notebook?

Tags: jupyter, vega

Am trying to copy paste the example from vega but am getting "vega is not defined" errors.

```
%%html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Import Vega 5 & Vega-Lite 3 (does not have to be from CDN) -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@[5]"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@[5]"></script>
  <!-- Import vega-embed -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@[5]"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="vis"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var spec = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vega/vega/master/docs/examples/bar-chart.vg.json";
  vegaEmbed('#vis', spec).then(function(result) {
    // Access the Vega view instance (https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/api/view/) as result.view
  }).catch(console.error);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there something special about how jupyterlab treats html/js in the magic that breaks this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind installing altair, you can do this:

```
from altair.vega import vega
import json
with open("bar-chart.vg.json") as f:
    s = json.load(f)
vega(s)
```

This definitely works in Jupyter Lab, not sure about notebook

Answer (score 2):

The "head" declarations won't work in a Jupyter cel. You can try something like this to define vegaEmbed:

```
<script>
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/',
  paths: {
    "vega-embed":  "vega-embed@5?noext",
    "vega-lib": "vega-lib?@5noext",
    "vega-lite": "vega-lite@4?noext",
    "vega": "vega@5?noext"
  }
});

requirejs(["vega", "vega-embed"], function(vega, vegaEmbed) {
     console.log(vega.version);
     console.log(vegaEmbed.version);
     window.vegaEmbed=vegaEmbed;
     window.vega = vega;});
</script>
```

Then a cel with just the body HTML should work. (Note: tried this in a regular Jupyter notebook, not Jupyterlab.)

**UPDATE**:

This works in jupyter notebooks but not in JupyterLab:

```
%%html
<script>
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/',
  paths: {
    "vega-embed":  "vega-embed@5?noext",
    "vega-lib": "vega-lib?@5noext",
    "vega-lite": "vega-lite@4?noext",
    "vega": "vega@5?noext"
  }
});

requirejs(["vega", "vega-embed"], function(vega, vegaEmbed) {
     console.log(vega.version);
     console.log(vegaEmbed.version);
     window.vegaEmbed=vegaEmbed;
     window.vega = vega;});
</script>

<body>

<div id="vis"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var spec = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vega/vega/master/docs/examples/bar-chart.vg.json";
  vegaEmbed('#vis', spec).then(function(result) {
    // Access the Vega view instance (https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/api/view/) as result.view
  }).catch(console.error);
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Interesting ... this works in notebook but not yet in JupyterLab. Will try to fix that then paste an update in your answer.

Comment: Note there are various extensions for Jupyter Lab too: https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/file_formats.html#vega-vega-lite

Comment: Here's how to do it in Jupyter Lab: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66060197/display-vega-spec-in-jupyter-lab/66060198#66060198